# Cambiar nombres del recurso colors.xml en Android studio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy practicando Android Studio la parte de los recursos, mas especifico en la parte de colors. El archivo me vino de manera predeterminada con estos nombres y valores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento cambiar los nombres que aparecen ahí, en la pestaña diseño se borran los colores de las partes que cambie alguno de los nombres que aparecen en verde (purple_200, purple_500, etc...).

[image: Pestaña diseño después de cambiar los nombres]

¿Hay alguna manera de poder cambiar los nombres sin que esto afecte o borre totalmente los colores de la pestaña diseño?.

```
<resources>
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purpe_500">#9ccc65</color>
<color name="pure_700">#6b9b37</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: Hola, los recursos de colores son usados en muchos lados dentro de tu aplicación Android, tendrías que ir validando donde estas usando el nombre del recurso para hacer que coincidan. Los elementos de diseño generales se definen en **themes.xml** (nuevas versiones de proyecto android) o en **styles.xml** (versiones anteriores) podrías validar si por ahí estas usando los recursos @color/

Answer (score 1):

Se eliminan los colores porque el layout esta haciendo referencia a estos colores, si cambias el nombre estos no podrán ser cargados puesto que la referencia original se pierde.

```
<resources>
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purpe_500">#9ccc65</color>
<color name="pure_700">#6b9b37</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

Si deseas cambiar los nombres, ve al layout y ahí también cambia los nombres.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que hacer refactor a los nombres.
Selecciona el nombre q deseas cambiar y pulsa Shift+F6, el nombre se marcará con otro color, entonces borra y teclea el nombre seleccionado, pulsa Enter y el IDE se encargará de cambiar el nombre a en todos los objetos que estén haciendo referencia a este.
La otra variante sería, seleccionar el nombre que deseas editar->click derecho->Refactor->Rename y editas el nombre, obtendrás el mismo efecto. Saludos